# Using pyodbc with SQL join statement in Python

Tags: python, pandas, join, pyodbc

I am trying to join 2 tables in Python. (Using Windows, jupyter notebook.)

Table 1 is an excel file read in using pandas.

```
TABLE_1= pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx')
```

Table 2 is a large table in oracle database that I can connect to using pyodbc. I can read in the entire table successfully using pyodbc like this, but it takes a very long time to run.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM ORACLE.table_2"
cnxn = odbc.connect(##########)
TABLE_2 = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
```

So I would like to do an inner join as part of the pyodbc import, so that it runs faster and I only pull in the needed records. Table 1 and Table 2 share the same unique identifier/primary key.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM ORACLE.TABLE_1 INNER JOIN TABLE_2 ON ORACLE.TABLE1.ID=TABLE_2.ID"
cnxn = odbc.connect(##########)
TABLE_1_2_JOINED = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
```

But this doesn't work. I get this error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM ORACLE.TABLE_1
INNER JOIN TABLE_2 ON ORACLE.TABLE1.ID=TABLE_2.ID': ('42S02', '[42S02]
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist\n (942)
(SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Is there another way I can do this? It seems very inefficient to have to import entire table w/millions of records when I only need to join a few hundred. Thank you.

Comment: Does you `TABLE_1` also exist in the database?

Comment: No, TABLE_1 only exists in excel and I have imported it using pandas pd.read_excel() method.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work.
First do:

```
MyIds = set(table_1['id'])
```

Then:

```
SQL1 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MyIds ( ID int );"
```

Now insert your ids:

```
SQL2 = "INSERT INTO MyIds.ID %d VALUES %s"
for element in list(MyIds):
    cursor.execute(SQL2, element)
```

And lastly

```
SQL3 = "SELECT * FROM ORACLE.TABLE_1 WHERE ORACLE.TABLE1.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MyIds)"
```

I have used MySQL not oracle and a different connector to you but the principles are probably the same. Of course there's a bit more code with the python-sql connections etc. Hope it works, otherwise try to make a regular table rather than a temporary one.